# FFmpeg memory leak in fragmented MP4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, fmp4

When using the FFmpeg console for saving an RTSP stream to a fragmented MP4 file I noticed there is a small memory leak.
It leaks approx 3-4 MB per hour (when each frame is a fragment and 30 fps).

The following command was used:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i rtsp://10.50.1.16/media/video3 -vcodec copy -an -f mp4 -frag_duration 1000 -movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+omit_tfhd_offset -loglevel quiet "c:\MemoryLeakTest.mp4"
```

[you can see here a perfmon set over 5 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p92A0.png)

This leak seems to be linear in time and related to the number of fragments written to the file.

**It was also reproducible also with the FFmpeg libraries.**

Has anyone encountered something like this?

Comment: I don't know if it can help you, but I found this question about generating fragmented mp4

Comment: Should be posted to the bug tracker.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the `skip_trailer` movflag.  See the following patch.
https://patchwork.libav.org/patch/61014/

Comment: Works great!
Do you perhaps know if such an index is also saved when demuxing a fragmented MP4 stream?

Comment: That's the correct answer, which also fixes fmp4 playback stutter in both HLS and DASH streams.

Answer (score 0):

To detect memory leaks you could compile FFmpeg from sources with debug symbols and then start with some memory debugging, memory leak detection tool. For example, take a look at [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)